# Tree structure with reference to root in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, tree, ef-code-first

I'm trying to model a tree structure for orders in Entity Framework. Right now I've go the following:

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProjectNode> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectNode
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual List<ProjectNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is get a reference to the root `ProjectModel` at any level of `ProjectNode` in order to authorize a given user actually having permission to view and change the project which contains the `ProjectNode`.

```
public class ProjectNode {
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }  //<-- this
...

public class ProjectModel {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }         //<-- containing the value of this
}
```

My question is whether its possible to have a theoretical `ProjectId` property populated at every level of the tree structure, or if I need to set it manually.

I had something working that at first blush appeared to allow this functionality, but upon further investigation only populated the `ProjectId` for `ProjectNode`s contained in the `ProjectModel`'s `Nodes` property.

It seems to me like it would be super inefficient to recurse backwards through the structure to get to the root.

Comment: You should keep key names the same across tables. `Id` under `ProjectModel` should be `ProjectModelID` and have the same name under `ProjectNode`. It keeps everything easy to read. As for your question, are you asking if children can exist without parents?

Comment: My question (which I may have phrased poorly) is: is there a way to automatically propagate the root `ProjectModel` Id to all `ProjectNode`s underneath it? Or now that I think about it more, even better, to propagate the `ProjectModel`'s `CustomerId` to any and all descendants? I have it working so that all descendants directly under the root `ProjectModel` automatically get a field from the model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit due to @TestWell for this answer -

Apparently, all I needed to do for EF to automatically populate the `ProjectId` property on the `ProjectNode` was to change the name of the `Id` property in `ProjectModel` to `ProjectId`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work if I add a `CustomerId` property to the `ProjectNode` that I would like automatically populated from the property of the same name on the node's root `ProjectModel`, which I realized is the more efficient solution to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Try adding `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }` under `public int CustomerId { get; set; }` in your `ProjectNode` entity, if you haven't already. Also, hit the check mark under the up/down vote buttons of your answer to 'mark as answer' and give yourself some reputation. And don't forget to do the same if someone answers your question :)

Comment: Thinking about this more, you don't need to add `CustomerId` to `ProjectNode`.. Just add `public virtual ProjectModel Model { get; set; }` to `ProjectNode` and call `nodeVariable.Model.CustomerId` when you need `CustomerId`. This is the more correct way of doing it, disregard my previous comment except the part about marking answers.